# How do I give missed messages to an ActionCable client upon reconnection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actioncable

From my testing, messages sent while an ActionCable client becomes temporarily disconnected from the internet are never delivered to that client when they reconnect.

If I wanted to support this, what would be the best practice for achieving this? I assume I'd need to somehow add a serial number to each message sent and also store those messages for a period of time (say 2 minutes?), then in the client, keep track of the serial number of the last message received and send that to the server upon reconnection. One would presumably force a reload (or a reload of all the data) if the 2 minute time was breached?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41203781/action-cable-how-to-deliver-missed-chat-messages seems to suggest a similar approach - store messages in your DB and on the client - compere after every reconnect and resend as necessary